# Mercurial API: hg.repository with https

Tags: python, api, mercurial, https

I'm trying to write a simple script that clones an existing Mercurial kiln repository that uses https authentications. I have this snippet:

```
from mercurial import hg, ui

repo = hg.repository(ui.ui(), "https://something.kilnhg.com/...")
```

Normally, whenever I would clone this repo or something, Mercurial would ask me to authenticate myself with a username and password. Instead, the above snippet just isn't getting authorized and gives me this error:

```
[a bunch of tracebacks...]
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\mercurial\url.py", line 131, in find_user_password
    raise util.Abort(_('http authorization required'))
mercurial.error.Abort: http authorization required
```

How can I pass my username and password to the `hg.repository` function? I've looked at both the source to hg.py and ui.py, but neither were helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try setting those directly to the url.

> https://username:password@something.kilnhg.com/...

Comment: I tried this before, it wasn't worked since I had a "@" in my username. I finally figured out that I should urlescape it. Working now.